# ios7 musicplay in background with time

Tags: time, ios7, background-process, duration, audio-player

Music player in ios7 change

First I find "remoteControlReceivedWithEvent" changed in ios7,as,"UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:" is useless and change to
"UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause:"
"UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay:"

and then I found ios7 MuiscPlay in bacground appear time.. and my player's time is empty like this:https://www.dropbox.com/s/l84wxl2jl4z3hr3/2013-11-11%2019.09.36.png

and how can I get the time with duration and current..

Thank you for your reading, hope you can help me。